# Getting order of sortable list in form input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using [HTML5 Sortable](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) to sort an ordered list of items, and when the change is made, I'd like to capture that order in a hidden form input.

With what I have below, the value of the hidden input is *[object HTMLOListElement]*.

What do I need to do to convert that into the values of the list items instead?

```
$('.sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function() {
    var order = $('.sortable').toArray();
    $('#statements').val(order.join(','));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var data = "";

        $(".sortable").each(function(i, el){
            var ord = $(el).text();
            data += ord+"="+$(el).index()+",";
        });

        $('#statements').val(data);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly exactly what I want. :)